# Registration of Shell Extension for specific file type

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, shell-extensions

I can sucessfully register my shell extension dll for all file types under the HKCR * key, but when I try to register it for a specific file type it fails.

Do you know what might the problem is?

The registration .rgs file is:

```
HKCR
{
    NoRemove CLSID
    {
        ForceRemove {BED8B9FD-1972-4E1E-B106-B576C5620C82} = s 'MyAppShellExt Class'
        {           
            InprocServer32 = s '%MODULE%'
            {
                val ThreadingModel = s 'Apartment'
            }           
        }
    }

    NoRemove .jpg
    {
        NoRemove ShellEx
        {
            NoRemove ContextMenuHandlers
            {
                ForceRemove MyApp = s '{BED8B9FD-1972-4E1E-B106-B576C5620C82}'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "It fails" Be precise by what this means.

Answer (score 0):

You really should not be writing anything to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` directly.  Write to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` and/or `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software`Classes` instead. Microsoft says as much in the [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT documentaton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724475.aspx).

Comment: HKCR is just an alias for HKLM\Software\Classes.  No argument about HKCU.  Could you please expand on your answer?

Comment: Read the documentation I linked to. `HKCR` is not a simple alias for `HKLM\Software\Classes`.  It is a single view of both `HKLM\Software\Classes` and `HKCU\Software\Classes` merged together.  When you create a new key or write a value to `HKCR` directly, it will get directed to either `HKCU` or `HKLM` depending on various criteria.

Comment: I tried to to register it under HKLM\Software\Classes but the menu item did not show up. When i register it for * and not for a specific file type it appears. What's the problem ?